# How to run tests from an external assembly

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, testing, mstest

Here's what I'm trying to achieve. I'm providing some code through a nuget and want to also publish a second nuget containing tests to verify the service is working/deployed correctly. This test nuget would contain all the core tests to do so without any modification needed (except through config files).

So here's the base class from **Assembly A**:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseTestClass
{
    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        // do some cleanup...
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BaseTest()
    {
        // base test code...
    }
}
```

And now, I want to reference this **Assembly A** into another **Assembly B** and do something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class ChildTestClass : BaseTestClass
{ }
```

The problem is, the test explorer doesn't see the *BaseTest* method. It will only see test methods that are declared in the child class itself. Any test methods from the base class are not discovered properly.

How could I do that?

FYI: it's working fine when I do the same thing but all in the same Assembly/project. I'm using both MSTest and ReSharper test runner. MSTest doesn't show anything but ReSharper sometimes shows the base tests but never run it, even if I'm able to select and run a specific one, it will always run only tests declared in the child class.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders, thank you for your edit. I was not aware of this rule.

Comment: Try out NUnit 2.6.4.  I just moved one of my TestBaseClass to a separate DLL and it continued to work.  Not an answer, at least not the one you are looking for but still an option even if migrating is somewhat labor intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to be the bearer of bad news, but simply put you cannot.

Visual Studio does not support this. There is a userVoice item to hopefully add support in the future, but until then you cannot build your tests this way.

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6030736-support-test-inheritance-for-base-classes-in-diffe

FYI official MS response confirming it:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/989781

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I also understand that this is specific to MSTest, what about using Resharper? Could it work?

Comment: Seems likely, although I am not privy to how their test runner works internally. If it just passes through to the MSTest assemblies under the covers it could suffer from the same bug. If not I would think it would have a high likelihood of working. If I had a copy of Re#er I would try to spin up a quick test of it for you, but I stopped using it awhile ago because my main solution is too large to work with it.